# Web Service to Get Current UTC Time?

Tags: php, web-services, utc, gmt

I'm building a PHP web application and need to know what the current date/time is. I cannot depend on the server's setting. Any web service I can use? I know there will be some delay accessing the time via web service, but I am fine with something that is not accurate to the last millisecond.

Comment: [Tsk tsk tsk, you forgot rule number one.  Always ask Google first.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=current+time&fp=1).  (Seriously, though, use an NTP server.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, get it from a public NTP server.

Look at a PHP implementation here:

http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php